# How to force reticulate to use WSL2 Ubuntu conda environment on a Windows installation of R

Tags: r, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, reticulate

I'm currently running R+RStudio on a Windows machine. I have WSL2 installed with an Ubuntu environment set up. Within that environment I have a number of mamba environments that I use for various jobs. I'm trying to use reticulate in R but it keeps looking for a python / conda windows executable. It appears to be hardcoded to look for windows files and strugles to work with my WSL2 locations.

I've mapped `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\\` to `U:\\`

```
> library(reticulate)
> 
> python.loc <- "U:\\home/.../mambaforge/bin/python"
> use_python(python.loc)
Error in system2(command = python, args = shQuote(script), stdout = 
TRUE,  : 
  '"U:/home/.../mambaforge/bin/python.exe"' not found
> conda.env <- "U:\\home/.../mambaforge/envs/python_scvi/bin/"
> use_condaenv(condaenv = conda.env)
Error: Unable to find conda binary. Is Anaconda installed?
>
```

Comment: Your Windows R can't run Ubuntu Python. WSL essentially lets you run two operating systems at the some time but they still can't share executables. If you want to use ubunto python, then you'll need to install R on ubuntu as well. reticulate can't cross the OS border.

Comment: That's what I figured but I wanted to check. The issue that I have is the code I'm running relies on things like jax which isn't properly supported on Windows and requires lots of extra steps to build on a windows environment. My painful workaround so far has been to just save the R object I'm working on and then run the necessary steps in a unix environment and then copy it back...

Comment: Have you considered moving your R environment to WSL? Either through RStudio Server running in WSL or vscode.